# Find not duplicated rows in dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to check dataframe with duplicates rows, with multiply condition and select them :
My input:

```
 task_id frame  m_label
0   466   15    Other
1   466  376    Other
2   466  376    Snapshot
3   466  5053   Transverse
4   466  5053   Snapshot
5   466  5280   Snapshot
6   477  11740  General
7   477  11740  Snapshot
```

So I need check if in same 'task_id' and same 'frame', 'm_label' was Snapshot and *somethingelse*
For example here, 'task_id' 466, 'frame' 376 have two different labels: one is necessarily Snapshot and another is Other. Also frame 5053 or in 'task_id' 477 frame 11740 fit condition. So it fit my condition. On other hand frame 5280 not good it's have only one label Snapshot. So I need add column that say it's only Snapshot in this frame.
For clear. I need find and label only where "Snapshot" in specific task and frame was only one, without any other tags in same frame in task
Excepted output:
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your two columns and apply your tests with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.transform.html):

```
df['Test'] = (df.groupby(['task_id', 'frame'])
                ['m_label']
                .transform(lambda x: len(x)<2 and
                                     'Snapshot' in x.values
                           )
                .map({True: 'Only one', False: ''})
              )
```

output:

```
   task_id  frame     m_label      Test
0      466     15       Other          
1      466    376       Other          
2      466    376    Snapshot          
3      466   5053  Transverse          
4      466   5053    Snapshot          
5      466   5280    Snapshot  Only one
6      477  11740     General          
7      477  11740    Snapshot
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough. I need find and label only where "Snapshot" in specific task and frame was only one, without any other tags in same frame in task

Comment: Well, I read it again several times and your explanation is really unclear. (1) Please provide the expected output, (2) please make an effort to explain clearly chat you expect.

Comment: Added expected output

Comment: I updated the answer. Honestly, you could have figured it out by yourself from the initial answer.